# How to make image into a link without losing the styling? and put the right side without overflow

Tags: html, css, image, web

I have 2 problems with this little project.

1.I want to make the image work as link,but everytime when I write the`<a>` tag before the `<img>` ,the picture becomes very little,like 8x8 pixel.

2.As you can see,I have text after the image,which aligned to the center. In the `<span>` I have entered a name : **"John"**,now If I type something longer,like: **"John Williams"**,the text will go beyond on the screen.Now, how can I do that,if I type something longer text,the picture and text will automatically shift to the left?And the text need to be in 1 line.

Is this possible? Because I haven't found any solution.

Thank you in advance for your help

Check guys, what I want exactly,so I want to put the image to the right side of the screen,and if I type something longer,for example in this code:"Joooooooooooooohn",the picture and the text will shift to the left side,like this without puting the `margin-right: 250px` to the `.box a{`

```css
.box a{
   float: right;
   display: inline-flex;
  margin-right: 250px;
   align-items:center; 
   width: 72px;
   height: 72px;
}
.image {
  width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.box span {
  padding-left:10px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-weight:700;
  font-size: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

  <a href="www.google.com"> 
   <img class="image" 
    src="https://c1.hiqcdn.com/blog/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/shareiq_5c1b489597ed5_1545291925.622325.jpg" 
    draggable="false">
   </img>
   <span>Joooooooooooooohn</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.box a{
   display: inline-flex;
   align-items:center; 
   width: 72px;
   height: 72px;
}
.image {
  width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.box span {
  padding-left:10px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-weight:700;
  font-size: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

  <a href="www.google.com"> 
   <img class="image" 
    src="https://c1.hiqcdn.com/blog/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/shareiq_5c1b489597ed5_1545291925.622325.jpg" 
    draggable="false">
   </img>
   <span>Joooooooooooooohn</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is solves the 1st problem,but do you have idea for the 2nd problem?

Comment: i entered long text and it is in one line

Comment: Check my last answer,how I want